# Show that formally real fields can be totally ordered into ordered fields

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields

A field $F$ is said to be formally real if the only solution to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_{i}^{2}}=0$ is the trivial solution $x_{i}=0$, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How do I show that there exists a total ordering $\geq$ on a formally real field $F$ so that $(F,+,\cdot,\geq)$ becomes an ordered field?

Comment: Not going to take the time to write an answer right now, but, the easiest way I know to do this is to first show it can be extended to a real closed field, and then restrict the order from that.  Probably more involved than you'd like, but there you go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SKETCH: First show that if $F$ is formally real, then the equation $-1=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$ has no solution in $F$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then let $\mathscr{P}$ be the set of *prepositive cones* in $F$. That is, $\mathscr{P}$ is the set of $P\subseteq F$ such that:

- for all $x,y\in P$, $x+y,xy\in P$:
- for all $x\in F$, $x^2\in P$; and
- $-1\notin P$.

Show that $\mathscr{P}\ne\varnothing$. HINT: Consider the set of all sums of squares of elements of $F$. Then use Zorn’s lemma to get $P\in\mathscr{P}$ that is maximal with respect to $\subseteq$. Finally, show that $P$ is a positive cone for $F$, i.e., that $F=P\cup(-P)$.

**Added:** It will be helpful to show that if $P\in\mathscr{P}$, and $x\in F\setminus P$, then either

$$P\cup\{x\}\subseteq P+Px\in\mathscr{P}\;,$$

or

$$P\cup\{-x\}\subseteq P+P(-x)\in\mathscr{P}\;,$$

where $P+Py=\{p+qy:p,q\in P\}$. The hardest part of this is showing that $-1$ cannot belong to both $P+Px$ and $P+P(-x)$. For this a preliminary result is useful: if $y\ne 0$, then at least one of $y$ and $-y$ does not belong to $P$.

To prove this, suppose that $y,-y\in P$. Then $y(-y)=-y^2\in P$. But by hypothesis $(y^{-1})^2\in P$, so $-1=(-y^2)(y^{-1})^2\in P$, which is impossible.

Now if $-1\in P+Px$ and $-1\in P+P(-x)$, then there are $p,q,r,s\in P$ such that $p+qx=-1=r-sx$. And $1\in P$ (why?), so if $p'=p+1$ and $r'=r+1$, then $p',r'\in P$. Moreover, $p'+qx=0=r'-sx$, so

$$\frac{-p'}q=x=\frac{r'}s\;.$$

But then $-p's=r'q\in P$, and $p's\in P$, contradicting the previous result.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on the usage of Zorn's lemma? I haven't quite got the hang of it yet, even though I have seen it before in the context of rings. I was able to show that $\mathscr{P} \neq \emptyset$ using your hint, but am not clear on what follows next.

Comment: @udit.m: Zorn’s lemma says that if chain in the partial order $\langle\mathscr{P},\subseteq\rangle$ has an upper bound in $\mathscr{P}$, then $\mathscr{P}$ has a maximal element. Thus, you need to show that if $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain in $\langle\mathscr{P},\subseteq\rangle$, then it has an upper bound in $\mathscr{P}$. To say that $\mathscr{C}$ is a chain is just to say that for any $C_0,C_1\in\mathscr{C}$, either $C_0\subseteq C_1$ or $C_1\subseteq C_2$. An upper bound for $\mathscr{C}$ would be a $P\in\mathscr{P}$ such that $C\subseteq P$ for each $C\in\mathscr{C}$. A natural candidate ...

Comment: ... is $\bigcup\mathscr{C}$; all that needs to be checked is that this union really is an element of $\mathscr{P}$.

Comment: I tried but was unable to do the last step viz. showing that $F = P \cup (-P)$. I think the argument goes like this: suppose $\exists x \in F$ s.t. $x \notin P$ and $-x \notin P$. Then I need to show there exists a prepositive cone containing $P$ and either $x$ or $-x$, giving a contradiction since $P$ was supposed to be the maximal element in $\mathscr{P}$. I'm having trouble constructing this prepositive cone.

Comment: @udit.m: That's a bit harder than I realized, so I've added to my answer; see if you can finish it from there. (It may not be as well-organized as sometimes, since I'm away from my computer and typing on a Kindle; I'll look in later to see whether it needs to be cleaned up.)