# Ordering on $R[\sqrt{n}]$ for an ordered ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordered-rings

I'm interested in showing that if $R$ is an ordered ring (with ordering $\leq$), and $n \geq 0$, then $R[\sqrt{n}]$ is also an ordered ring.

In the reals, $0 \leq a_1 + a_n\sqrt n$ iff either (1) $0 \leq a_1$ and $na_n^2 \leq a_1^2$, or (2) $0 \leq a_n$ and $a_1^2 \leq na_n^2$.  So it seems natural to define the set $P$ of nonnegative elements of $R[\sqrt{n}]$ by the rule

- $a_1 + a_n\sqrt{n} \in P$ iff (1) or (2) above hold

However, I'm having trouble proving that $x \in P$ and $y \in P$ implies $x + y \in P$.  It seems like it should be elementary, but I'm finding myself running around in circles.

I've been trying to split the proof into cases, depending on whether $x$ and $y$ satisfy rules (1) or (2).  The cases where they both satisfy (1) or both satisfy (2) are easy, but the casework is getting overwhelming when $x$ satisfies (1) and $y$ satisfies (2).

I wonder if anyone can suggest something I'm missing, or maybe point me to a more general theorem that would help (although I'd like to avoid getting too esoteric since my eventual goal is to formulate the proof in coq).

Thanks!

**Update:** I’ve made progress but am still stuck.  Unless I’m mistaken, the only case I need is to show that $0 \leq (x_1 + x_n\sqrt{n}) + (y_1 + y_n\sqrt{n})$ when the following conditions all hold:

- $0 \leq x_1$
- $0 \leq -x_n$
- $nx_n^2 \leq x_1^2$
- $0 \leq -y_1$
- $0 \leq y_n$
- $y_1^2 \leq ny_n^2$
- $0 \leq x_1 + y_1$
- $0 \leq -x_n - y_n$

Combining these assumptions gives $0 \leq y_1^2 \leq ny_n^2 \leq n x_n^2 \leq x_1^2$.

In this case I need to show that $n(x_n + y_n)^2 \leq (x_1 + y_1)^2$.

I’ve tried playing with fractions, derivatives, absolute values, and just can’t solve this case.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just checking, your rings include unity  and $n$ here refers to the unit element added $n$ times,   with the $\sqrt n$ being an adding element to solve the equation $x^2-n=0$ and $\sqrt n>0$?

Comment: @Alan Unless $n$ is already a square in $R$, in which case $R[\sqrt n]=R$, is my guess.

Comment: @Alan I don't see a reason not to assume that $n$ is a generic element of $R$.

Comment: Presumably $R$ is commutative for otherwise elements of the form $a+b\sqrt{n}$ don't form a ring. So $R$ is an ordered integral domain, and we can also order its field of fractions $Q(R)$. Then we define $r>\sqrt{n}$ if $r>0$ and $r^2>n$ for all $r\in Q(R)$. The rest "naturally". Then it is easy to prove the following: If $r>\sqrt{n}$, $s>\sqrt{n}$ and $\alpha,\beta\in Q(R)$ are both non-negative and satisfy the constraint $\alpha+\beta=1$, then we also have
$$\alpha r+\beta s>\sqrt{n}.$$ I haven't checked, but I think this will take care of many cases.

Comment: (cont'd) The idea being that switching to the field of fractions gives us the ability to "scale" by positive factors, and that should simplify things. The above observation then gives "affine combination" that seem to be needed. But, I'm prepared to be very wrong about something. Also, this feels unnecessarily complicated, but I have never done this exercise, so I don't know what it takes. Letting my intuition take over even though it is beginning to fail :-(

Comment: @alan My rings are commutative and unital; but n is an arbitrary element.

Comment: @Jykri Working in the FoF makes sense, though it wasn’t helping me much.  I’m not sure I’m seeing how to use your lemma, although I think focusing on comparing with $\sqrt{n}$ instead of with 0 might be promising.

Comment: The idea is that when $x_1,x_n,y_1,y_n$ are all positive and we assume that $x_1-x_n\sqrt{n}$ and $y_1-y_n\sqrt{n}$ are both positive (surely the interesting cases are when $x_1$ and $x_n$ have opposite signs), then both $x_1/x_n$ and $y_1/y_n$ are both $>\sqrt n$. Then the observation in the above comment tells us that $(x_1+y_1)/(y_1+y_)$ is also $>\sqrt n$. Or $(x_1+y_1)-(x_n+y_n)\sqrt n$ is positive. This is basically the familar fact that with $a,b,c,d$ positive integers, the *mediant* $(a+c)/(b+d)$ is in the interval $[a/b, c/d]$.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't handle the cases where $x$ and $y$ have "opposite types". That is, the case with $x=x_1-x_n\sqrt n$, $y=-y_1+y_n\sqrt n$, all the unknowns again positive.

Comment: Yes @Jyrki, this last case is the one I'm stuck on.

Comment: @mdgeorge It may be possible to use "a suitable variant of the mediant" to still conclude. Care needs to be exercised because this time the fractions $x_1/x_n$ and $y_1/y_n$ are on opposite sides of $\sqrt{n}$. Will post an answer, if I figure out something nice.

Comment: @Jyrki thanks, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are scores of details to check, but the following seems to handle the most difficult cases.

Below $a,b,c,d$ will always denote arbitrary positive elements of $R$, so for example $-a<0$.

---

Assuming that $R$ is an integral domain we can extend its ordering to its field of fractions $F$. Next I define that a fraction $a/b$, both $a,b$ positive elements of $R$, is $>\sqrt n$ if and only if $a^2>n b^2$ in $R$. Obviously the negative fractions are all $<\sqrt n$. It is trivial to show that equal fractions behave compatibly.

At this point we have, in a sense, defined where $\sqrt{n}$ lies on the number line of $F$. We still need to check that this is compatible with the ordering of $F$. To that end we prove the result.

**Lemma 1.** If $c/d>\sqrt n$ and $a/b>c/d$ then $a/b>\sqrt n$.

**Proof.** We have $c^2/d^2>n$ and $a^2/b^2>c^2/d^2$ so $a^2/b^2>n$ and the claim follows.

Next we define the set of positive elements of $R[\sqrt n]$ by declaring that

> $a+b\sqrt n$ is always positive, $-a-b\sqrt n$ is always negative,
> and then in the mixed cases
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> a-b\sqrt n>0&\Longleftrightarrow a/b>\sqrt n,\\
> -a+b\sqrt n>0&\Longleftrightarrow a/b<\sqrt n.
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Handle the cases $a=0$ and $b=0$ in the obvious way. I think this is equivalent to the OP's definition of positive elements of $R[\sqrt n]$, but I choose to work in $F$, so rephrase it this way.

The goal is to show that the set of positive numbers thus defined is closed under addition. I will only handle the mixed case numbers, for I think those are the most delicate ones.

---

Remembering that *the mediant* $(a+c)/(b+d)$ lies between $a/b$ and $c/d$ will play a key role. We also need to look at what happens with $(a-c)/(b-d)$ when $b>d$.
The model I kept in mind is to compare the following rationals with $\sqrt3$:
$$
\frac21>\frac74>\sqrt 3>\frac{17}{10}>\frac53.
$$

- Here the mediant $(7+2)/(1+4)=9/5$ will automatically be $>\sqrt3$ as the mediant is $>7/4$. Similarly the mediant $(17+5)/(10+3)$ will automatically be $<\sqrt 3$ as it is below $17/10$.
- With $a/b=7/4$ and $c/d=5/3$, so $b>d$, we see that $(a-c)/(b-d)=2/1$ is actually above $a/b$. This is also because $7/4$ is the mediant of $2/1$ and $5/3$.
- Similarly with $a/b=17/10$ and $c/d=7/4$ (again $b>d$) the fraction
  $(a-c)/(b-d)=10/6=5/3$ is below $a/b$. This is because $17/10$ is below $7/4$, and also the mediant of $7/4$ and $10/6$.

These inequalities generalize easily in the indicated way and give us the claim. Behold.

---

**Lemma 2.** If $x$ and $y$ are positive elements of $R[\sqrt n]$, so is $x+y$.

My proof only covers the mixed cases for I think the rest are easier. I split it into cases according to what types of mixed cases we have.

**Case I.** $x=a-b\sqrt n, y=c-d\sqrt n$.

In this case we have $a/b>\sqrt n$ and $c/d>\sqrt n$. The mediant
$$
\frac{a+c}{b+d}=\alpha \frac ab+\beta \frac cd
$$
with $\alpha=b/(b+d)$, $\beta=d/(b+d)$ both positive. Furthermore $\alpha+\beta=1$. These imply that $(a+b)/(c+d)$ is between $a/b$ and $c/d$. By Lemma 1 we can conclude that
$(a+b)/(c+d)>\sqrt n$. Consequently $x+y=(a+b)-(c+d)\sqrt n$ is positive.

**Case II.** $x=a-b\sqrt n$, $y=-c+d\sqrt n$.

This time we know that $a/b>\sqrt n$ and $c/d<\sqrt n$.

Here $x+y=(a-c)-(b-d)\sqrt n$, so we need to compare $(a-c)/(b-d)$ with $\sqrt n$. We need to further split this into two cases according to which denominator, $b$ or $d$, is larger (the case $b=d$ is trivial).

Assume first that $b>d$. Our goal is to show that $(a-c)/(b-d)>\sqrt n$. We can reuse the result about the mediant from Case I simply by observing that $a/b$ is the mediant of $(a-c)/(b-d)$ and $c/d$. Therefore $a/b$ lies in between the other two fractions. As $a/b>c/d$ we can conclude that $(a-c)/(b-d)>a/b$.
Again, by Lemma 1, we have $(a-c)/(b-d)>\sqrt n$ proving the claim.

On the other hand when $d>b$ we have $x+y=-(c-a)+(d-b)\sqrt n$, and thus we need to show that $(c-a)/(d-b)<\sqrt n$. This follows similarly by observing that $c/d$ is the mediant of $a/b$ and $(c-a)/(d-b)$. This time the conclusion is that $(c-a)/(d-b)<c/d$.
As $c/d<\sqrt n$ the obvious counterpart of Lemma 1 implies that also $(c-a)/(d-b)<\sqrt n$.

Comment: Just noticed we only need the result about mediants. This simplifies the proof of Case II.

Comment: dear Jyrki; +1, but alternatively, once you have passed to the field of fractions, you can also work with positive cones instead of defining the order directly; this eliminates a lot of the necessary casework. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094582/f-sqrt-x-mid-x-0-is-formally-real/4094629#4094629)

Comment: (of course this all assumes that $R$ is an integral domain, but if OP is willing to use the definition of an ordered ring that involves strict orderings then indeed any ordered ring is a domain)

Comment: Thanks @AtticusStonestrom. Can't say I'm surprised to learn that this has been covered. Somehow I missed your post while searching :-(. Now the options are A) to let the bounty run its course and think about closing as a duplicate afterwards. B) Flag for moderator assistance.

Comment: dear Jyrki, no worries!!! :) since this question is framed in terms of orderings and the other is framed in terms of formally real fields it make sense that they didn't come up together in a duplicate search. I just commented to share the link with OP as well; perhaps we can see if they are satisfied with it? I'm also curious whether anyone can come up with a nice solution in the case when $R$ is not an integral domain

Comment: @Jykri, thank you!  I want to run through the details to double check that everything works, but I think this solves it.  Once I’ve done that I’ll award the bounty.

Comment: Thanks @Atticus, I will work through your solution as well to see if it simplifies things

Comment: No rush with the bounty @mdgeorge! A simpler argument may still be coming!

Comment: @mdgeorge sounds good! :) feel free to let me know if you have any questions! I'm also interested to see if anyone can come up with a nice solution when $R$ is not an integral domain...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

I'm sure your method can be made to work, but like you said, the casework is rather tedious. Another approach might be to try the following. Working backwards, we should have

$$0 < a+b\sqrt{n} \iff -a < b \sqrt{n}$$

Now our dream is to "square both sides" in order to kill off the $\sqrt{n}$ and get left with something in $R$. The issue, of course, is that squaring kills all of our sign information! The clever trick, then? Without loss of generality, we want $\sqrt{n}$ to be positive, and for positive numbers $x$ and $|x|$ agree. But $|x|$ *preserves sign information* for negative numbers.

This observation might clue us in to look at the function $x \mapsto |x| \cdot x$. With this in mind, we can "square both sides" with our new and improved squaring function, to find

$$-a < b \sqrt{n} \iff -|a| \  a < |b| \ bn \iff 0 < |a|\ a + |b|\ bn$$

but this new condition is entirely checkable inside $R$. Can you show that it works as a good definition of the positive elements of $R[\sqrt{n}]$ whenever $n > 0$ in $R$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks!  I was playing with this formulation, but it didn’t seem to help a lot, because trying to prove inequalities with the absolute values was leading me to consider the case analysis again.  Maybe the triangle inequality would help somehow, but I’m not seeing it.  I’ll try pushing more in this direction though.